# Apache 2 certs on different domains

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I have apache serve setup with example domains domain1.com and domain2.com

My ssl.conf (etc/apache2/modes-enabled/ssl.conf)

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost 172.17.0.122:443>
ServerAdmin info@domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs
ServerName domain1.com:443
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol all
SSLCertificateFile    /var/ssl/domain1/domain1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/domain1.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ssl/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.17.0.123:443>
ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/htdocs/
ServerName domain2.com:443
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol all
SSLCertificateFile    /var/ssl/domain2/domain2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/domain2.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ssl/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

domain1 works fine with http and https, domain2 works only with http, since domain2 https shows domain1 page... I have 2 ips on server.

VirtualHost (etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com) for domain1:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin info@domain1.com
       ServerName  www.domain1.com
        ServerAlias domain1.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/domain1.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /var/www/domain1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2ctl -S shows:

```
VirtualHost configuration: 
172.17.0.122:443 www.domain1.com (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:77)
 wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers: 
*:* is a NameVirtualHost default server www.domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain3.com:1) 
port * namevhost www.domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain3.com:1)
port * namevhost www.domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com:1)
port * namevhost www.domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com:1)
```

this is with config that shows domain1 https corectly

Comment: ... Good grief. Search all your config files for `NameVirtualHost` stanzas and make sure none of them overlap. Especially that `*:*` one is damning and probably the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:443` from the ServerName stanzas. It's treated as part of the name, and when *no* VirtualHost ServerName entry matches, Apache serves up the first VirtualHost site it finds.

**EDIT** d'oy. Also, take a good look at your `NameVirtualHost` statement as it contrasts with your `VirtualHost` stanzas.

You're announcing there will be multiple VHosts using the address `*:443`, but then  specify your VHosts on `172.16.0.123:443`. These are different addresses and Apache will not acknowledge them.

Either change your `NameVirtualHost` statement or amend your `<VirtualHost>` stanzas so that they match.

Comment: I removed :443, also I edited question and added original * virtualHost for first domain which works fine for non https. tho still domain2 serve domain1 from https

Comment: So i need NameVirtualHost for both ips:443? Does apache need this for http aswell? If http works fine for now

Comment: You can only have VirtualHosts on addresses specified in a NameVirtualHost entry. If you're not sure, set them all to `*:443`.

Comment: I added NameVirtualHost 172.17.0.122:443 and NameVirtualHost 172.17.0.123:443 but still I can't get domain2 from https :(

Comment: Actually I have 172.17.0.122:443 as NameVirtualHost and below that <VirtualHost 172.17.0.122:443> but when I restart / reload apache, says [warn] 172.17.0.122:443 has no VirtualHosts.

Comment: Also [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts and [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: Urgh.. Did you read the documentation at all? First, set `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `*:443`. Then use `Virtualhost *:80` and `*:443` in your `<VirtualHost>` stanzas, and let SNI sort out which is which like nature intended.

Comment: I set NameVirtualHost *:80 on virtual.conf in conf.d, after that I get error `[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence` but default and default-ssl are disabled via a2dissite. also, I tried to grep default from apache folder but couldn't find any more. All pages try to go to their root I think because I get forbidden.

Comment: .. Please add those to the question rather than in a comment.

Comment: updated question, I assume all domains load domain3, for some reason when using VirtualHost *:80. https://debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2 is the guide pretty much has same setup as I do in virtual hosts, like I had before <VirtualHost *> on all... and NameVirtualHost * in virtual.conf